# Parallel program slower than serial one with pthread

Tags: macos, random, numbers, posix, generator

I have to use random numbers in my program. Know that rand() is not thread safe and it's why i've tried several methods: mutex to block it, srand,drand48...but my parallel program still slower than the serial one...Can someone help with it?

I use Mac book pro i5 with 2 cores.

```
   //
//  main.cpp
//  Dirihle_problem_monte_carlo_method (Posix threads)





#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>



// переменные
FILE *FileData, *FileResults;

int N = 200; // число равномерных случайных блужданий
int n = 51; // сетка n x n (шаг h=1)

int nInside; // сетка внутренних узлов (nInside-1) x (nInside-1)
float *presult;

int indexBegin, indexEnd;


int partSize;
int numOfLine;

#define NUM_THREADS 1

double conversion_factor;

//Raw mach_absolute_times going in, difference in seconds out
double subtractTimes( uint64_t endTime, uint64_t startTime );
float Monte_Carlo_Method(int N, int n, int i, int j);
bool borderLineNotReached(int i, int j, int n);
void *ParallelResultCalculation (void *threadid);
int indEnd(int treadID);



void Init() {
    mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
    conversion_factor = (double)timebase.numer / (double)timebase.denom;
}
#pragma mark - main
/*****************************************************************/
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int rc;

    uint64_t start,stop;
    double duration = 0.0;
    timeval beforeTime, afterTime;



//    Init();
    //инициализация системы и отправка необходимых данных остальным процессам
    //  FileData    = fopen("DataFile.txt","r");
    FileResults = fopen("FileResults.txt","w+");


    // Initialize and set thread joinable
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    //fscanf(FileData,"%d",&n);
    nInside = n - 1;

    //  fscanf(FileData,"%d",&N);

    numOfLine = (nInside - 1);
    partSize = numOfLine  / NUM_THREADS;

    presult = new float [n * n];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            {
                presult[i * n + j] = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (i == nInside)
            {
                presult[i * n + j] = j;
            }
            else if (j == nInside)
            {
                presult[i * n + j] = i;
            }
        }
    }



    start = mach_absolute_time();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
//        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ParallelResultCalculation, (void *)i);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, ParallelResultCalculation, (void *)i);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("Error:unable to create thread %d", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // free attribute and wait for the other threads
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("Error:unable to join thread %d", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }

    stop = mach_absolute_time();
    duration = subtractTimes(stop,start);



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            fprintf(FileResults, "u(%d,%d)= %lf\t", i, j, presult[i * n + j]);
        }
        fprintf(FileResults, "\n");
    }
    fprintf(FileResults, "\n\n Elapsed time(seconds) = %lf", duration);


    delete [] presult;
    //  fclose(FileData);
    fclose(FileResults);
    pthread_exit(NULL);


    return 0;
}






#pragma mark - function relative to time
/*****************************************************************/
double subtractTimes( uint64_t endTime, uint64_t startTime )
{
    uint64_t difference = endTime - startTime;
    static double conversion = 0.0;

    if( conversion == 0.0 )
    {
        mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
        kern_return_t err = mach_timebase_info( &info );

        //Convert the timebase into seconds
        if( err == 0  )
            conversion = 1e-9 * (double) info.numer / (double) info.denom;
    }

    return conversion * (double) difference;
}

#pragma mark - last id
int indEnd(int treadID)
{
    int index;
    if(treadID == NUM_THREADS - 1)
    {
        index = nInside;
    }
    else
    {
        index = (partSize * (treadID + 1)) + 1;
    }

    return index;
}

#pragma mark - Monte-Carlo method
/*****************************************************************/
float Monte_Carlo_Method(int N, int n, int i, int j)
{
    unsigned int rand_state;
    int randomValueForStep;
    //  int minRandom = 0;
    //  int maxRandom = 10; // 10 not included in interval



    do
    {
        // determine the direction of the step (look at "„исленные методы анализа", ƒемидович стр.272:
        // определение шага частицы в зависимости от выпавшего случайного числа)
        // algorithm   http://iguania.ru/stati-po-programmirovaniiu/generatsiya-sluchaynich-chisel.html
//        unsigned seed = getpid() * time(NULL) * (thrID + 1);
//        
//        randomValueForStep = rand_r(&seed) % 4;


//        randomValueForStep = rand() % 4;

        randomValueForStep = drand48() * 5.0;


//        rand_state = rdtsc();
//      randomValueForStep = rand_r(&rand_state) % 4;


        if (randomValueForStep == 0) // шаг вправо
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if (randomValueForStep == 1) // шаг вверх
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if (randomValueForStep == 2)// шаг влево
        {
            i--;
        }
        else if (randomValueForStep == 3) // шаг вниз
        {
            j--;
        }

    }
    while (borderLineNotReached(i, j, n));



    // блуждание частицы завершено, т.к она вышла на границу
    float res;
    if (j == 0) // нижняя граница (x,border_y0)
    {
        res = 0.0;
    }
    else if(i == n - 1) // правая граница (border_xmax,y)
    {
        res = j;
    }
    else if(j == n - 1) // верхняя граница (x,border_ymax)
    {
        res = i;
    }
    else {
        res = 0.0;
    }

    return res;
}

//bool borderLineNotReached(float i, float j, float border_x0, float border_y0, float border_xmax, float border_ymax)
bool borderLineNotReached(int i, int j, int n)
{
    if (i <= 0 || j <= 0 || i >= (n - 1) || j >= (n - 1))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}





void *ParallelResultCalculation (void *threadid)
//void *ParallelResultCalculation (void *data)
{
    int tid;

    tid = *((int *)&threadid);
//    struct thread_data *getData = (struct thread_data *)data;
//    tid = getData->thread_id;

    indexBegin = partSize * tid + 1;
    indexEnd   = indEnd(tid);




    for (int i = indexBegin; i < indexEnd; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < nInside; j++)
        {
            float sum = 0.0;
            float res;
            for (int indexOfTrajectory = 0; indexOfTrajectory < N; indexOfTrajectory++)
            {
                res = Monte_Carlo_Method(N, n, i, j);
                sum += res;
            }


            float uij = sum / (float)N;
            presult[i * n + j] = uij; // a[i,j]= [i*m+j], где i = 0...n, j = 0...m
        }

    }


//    pthread_exit(NULL);


}
```

Comment: Just because rand() isn't thread safe, doesn't mean including it in your program means you can't use threads.  You just have to be careful how you use rand() particularly that both threads don't call rand() at the same time.  It is very difficult to write a (non-trivial) program that won't see at least a little performance boost from threading.  Nothing in your code stands out to me as particularly non-performant, though I didn't read through all of it or benchmark in any way.  That's a lot of code.  If you post a specific part you're "curious" about I would dig in in more detail.

Comment: Well.thank you for your answer.sorry to post so a long code.today i've found that the program run correctly on windows with an acceleration.there was a supposition that the macbook doesn't really use both cores correctly.some person told me that i've to try to setting up attribute with pthread_attr_ser_scope.
He have already see such kind of problem with boost.

But i don't really know how to use this function.